# How can I debug what's happening inside a NSS library function?

Tags: c++, debugging, nss

I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of NSS lib's `PK11_PrivDecryptPKCS1` function in my code so I can pinpoint why it's failing. It's always returning a `SECFailure`.

I have seen [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/security/source/security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/pk11obj.c) that this function creates a parameter and calls `pk11_PrivDecryptRaw`.  Now in `pk11_PrivDecryptRaw` (same file, line 833) I saw that if can return `SECFailure` in 3 code blocks:

First if `key->keyType != rsaKey`. So I debuged `key->keyType` and saw it has equal to `rsaKey`.

The next part is this:

```
session = pk11_GetNewSession(slot,&owner);
(...)
crv = PK11_GETTAB(slot)->C_DecryptInit(session, mech, key->pkcs11ID);
if (crv != CKR_OK) {
    (...)
    return SECFailure;
}
```

So I replicated this code in my code in order to debug what's being returned to crv. When I tried to do this I had a lot of trouble finding the .h where some symbols where. It couldn't find the "`secmodi.h`", "`secmodti.h`" includes. I found them in the source code for the libnss3-dev.

Now the problem is with the linkage. I'm getting the error

undefined reference for `pk11_GetNewSession`. I searched the whole /usr/lib dir for this function, with this command:

```
find . -name \*.so -type f -print -exec readelf -s {} \; 2> /dev/null | grep "\.so\|PK11"
```

but it didn't find it. I'm thinking it should be and internal function from the library that is not exposed on the .so.

If I try to substitute this call for the code inside this function, I mean

```
PK11_GETTAB(slot)->C_OpenSession(slot->slotID,CKF_SERIAL_SESSION,slot,pk11_notify,&session)
```

I get an undefined reference for `pk11_notify` this time.

How can I debug this ?

Comment: Build the NSS library with debug information, link it to your application, step into the function with the debugger.

Comment: build instruction for nss library in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Reference/Building_and_installing_NSS/Build_instructions aren't working. A simple make gives this error: plarena.h: not found

Comment: Install the missing dependency (NSPR in this case).

Comment: libnspr4* packages are all installed